# AK4524 with Arduino

Tags: adc

I have some AK4524 ADC/DAC chips from an old M-Audio Delta 10/10 sound card in my hand.

I would like to use them for precision sensor reading and voltage generating with a arduino nano.

My experience with digital electronics is limited, i have used mcp4822 as a dac before with arduino and a bit familiar with SPI.

Would you point me to the right direction on this matter.

https://people.freebsd.org/~lofi/4524.pdf

This is the datasheet.

Thank you.

Comment: You can't use those with an Arduino Nano. You need a microcontroller that can generate a full duplex I2S data stream, and that usually means one of the 32-bit boards. Probably a Teensy 3.x is your best bet.

Comment: Also audio CODECs aren't really suitable for sensors.

Comment: Thank you very much, why would an audio codec not suitable for sensors? Because of the DC AC difference? Also would these be easy to interface with a Teensy?

Comment: They don't work quite the same as a voltage DAC like you're used to. They need a constant stream of data feeding to them to control the output voltage (which is a differential output, not single-ended), and the ADC gives a constant high speed stream of data - tens of thousands of readings per second. You can't just go "Set DAC A to 23" or "Get me the current ADC value from channel 1".

Comment: Thank you I will do more reading on the differences.